# how to set the height for a spinner dropdown list?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-spinner

How should I go about limiting the height of a spinner drop down ?
Suppose for example:

If I have a spinner drop down with total of 10 rows,
I would like to display only the first 3 rows,
and the rest of the content should be scrollable.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597584/how-to-limit-the-height-of-spinner-drop-down-view-in-android

Comment: @sasikumar I have tried the accepted answer from the link which uses reflection. But , it didn't work for me. Using that answer, i get a dialog type dropdown which covers the entire screen.

Comment: you can adjust height based on your phone size..in that link  code height is 500.

Comment: @sasikumar  I have tried that , still didn't work. it still takes up the full height of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default method in spinner to control number of items to display in drop-down. you can create your own spinner. refer this [link](https://github.com/ankitthakkar/DropDownSpinner), he has created a custom spinner that supports `setVisibleItemNo (int no)` method. you can try it. I didn't test it .but the code seems to be working. you can give a try.

```
/**
 * Set the height of DropDown spinner equal to number of visible rows
 * 
 * @param no
 *            - number (Integer) of visible item row
 */
public void setVisibleItemNo(int no) {
    this.visibleItemNo = no;
    setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lv);
}
```