# How to style spinner dropdown size?

Tags: android, styles, size, spinner

How to reduce spinner size like this, reduce it's width & move it's alignment to right. Please refer below screenshots

What I want is below

[image: I want spinner style like this]

What I get...

[image: What I get]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit the height of Spinner drop down view in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597584/how-to-limit-the-height-of-spinner-drop-down-view-in-android)

Comment: @AnkitaShah Height is not a problem for me. I want reduce width of spinner. Like half of parent width. Please help me

Comment: Set Width of spinner `Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
          int  leftPaneWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels / 2;popupWindow.setWidth(leftPaneWidth );`

Comment: Thanks @AnkitaShah I've achieved this using setDropDownWidth() property of spinner

Answer (score 0):

Set Width of spinner

`Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics(); display.getMetrics(outMetrics); 
int width = outMetrics.widthPixels / 2;
popupWindow.setWidth(width);`