# Unable to set height for Android Spinner popup in API 21 and 22

Tags: java, android, android-widget, field, android-spinner

Herewith I used 'spinner' with some styles. To set height of the spinner popup, I used 'List Popup Window'. It's working fine for more Android versions. But API 21 and 22 (Android 5.0 and 5.1) not supported. Below is my code that I found from [How to limit the height of Spinner drop down view in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597584/how-to-limit-the-height-of-spinner-drop-down-view-in-android).

**MainActivity.java**

```
Spinner newsSourceSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.news_spinner);

try {
    Field popup = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
    popup.setAccessible(true);

    // Get private mPopup member variable and try cast to ListPopupWindow
    android.widget.ListPopupWindow popupWindow = (android.widget.ListPopupWindow) popup.get(newsSourceSpinner);

    // set popup height
    popupWindow.setHeight(250);

} catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassCastException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    // silently fail...
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<Spinner
       android:id="@+id/news_spinner"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:textSize="13sp"
       style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
       android:theme="@style/SpinnerStyle"
       android:popupBackground="#80000000"
       android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
       android:focusable="true"/>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="SpinnerStyle">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```