# How to reduce the height of Drop Down in android?

Tags: java, android, spinner, dropdown

I am using default android spinner in my application. how to reduce the height of drop down as default methods are not working?

Answer (score 0):

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29959720/8068914)

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
try {
    Field popup = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
    popup.setAccessible(true);

    // Get private mPopup member variable and try cast to ListPopupWindow
    android.widget.ListPopupWindow popupWindow = (android.widget.ListPopupWindow) popup.get(spinner);

    // Set popupWindow height to 500px
    popupWindow.setHeight(500);
}
catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassCastException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    // silently fail...
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your kind response, @MoustafaShahin but tried above code but not working, any other alternative then please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

check this
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580791/13087029)

In my solution you put recycleview in spinner and then you put all the data to this rv, you can modify everything you want of the recycleview

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32629741)

Comment: Okey, thanks for advice! Next time I will do it properly

Answer (score -1):

By Using Refelection you can set height of dropdown

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    try {
        Field popup = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        popup.setAccessible(true);

        // Get private mPopup member variable and try cast to ListPopupWindow
        android.widget.ListPopupWindow popupWindow = (android.widget.ListPopupWindow) popup.get(spinner);

        // Set popupWindow height to 500px
        popupWindow.setHeight(500);
    }
    catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassCastException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // silently fail...
    }
```

If above does not work then Create class extend `Spinner` class overriding its `getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(Rect outRect)` which is used by `android.widget.PopupWindow` for calculations. Just set outRect to limit the area where drop down view can be displayed.

```
@Override
public void getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(Rect outRect) {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    d.getRectSize(outRect);
    outRect.set(outRect.left, <STATUS BAR HEIGHT>, outRect.right, outRect.bottom);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind response @chandmohd but tried above code not working, I couldn't find any linking of the above Override method to the spinner, how should I connect the above code of override method with spinner, what would be the reference. Please suggest

Comment: overridden getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame() never called