# How to limit the height of the dropdown Spinner view in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

[*enter image description here*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81wmM.png)
Query : I am creating 2-Spinner view , where i have to add Country/Cities list , So like if i am selecting india then i am getting 50 items inside the drop down view , problem with this is that it is taking the whole page in height .

What i want : I want to create a drop down view , where user can see only 10 items in the drop down view , other items will be shown whenever user will scroll the drop down view .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597584/how-to-limit-the-height-of-spinner-drop-down-view-in-android ? However, you got better options like `Exposed Dropdown Menus` and `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Comment: just calculate the size of wanted items and set it as the height of listView. for example each cell has 40Dp and you want to show 5 cell, 5*40=200Dp and set the listView height 200Dp