# Spinner goes off the screen when FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS is setted

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-spinner

I have some `Spinner` in my fragment, but since i need to do this

```
val window = requireActivity().window
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

the spinner doesn't find a bottom edge, so the list of items goes off the screen.

I founded this answer that seems to fix my problem, but I'm new to android I don't understand how to implement it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34763942/15566249

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your fragment's XML layout code?

Comment: Never mind, i didn't find a solution so i change the spinner with a `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`. Grazie comunque ;)