# android spinner with drop down for birthday

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface

i tried to customize the spinner but i never worked so if u can help me by adding this custom design functionally it works but i coudnt customize the design if there is any other alternavise let me know

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/yearSpinner"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:prompt="@string/select_year"/>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/monthSpinner"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:prompt="@string/select_month"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/daySpinner"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:prompt="@string/select_day"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

i want it to look like this
custom drops down spinner

Answer (score 0):

use `android:popupBackground="@drawable/spinner_popup_background"` for expanded layout and `android:background="@drawable/spinner_border"` for spinner border (outline). Design a custom background for expanded layout with stork width 2dp and stork color yellow. For example [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74903171/6576302). For more customization [see this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11188398/6576302)